# Persistent OAuth using Android and Twitter4J

Tags: android, twitter-oauth

So I am trying to get a grip around this `OAuth` for twitter using the `Twitter4J` library.

I will give a little bit of background.

I set up my Twitter developer account using the Browser method and callbacks (that I have set up as an intent-filter) in my `AndroidManifest.xml`.

I have an activity that entirely handles my twitter authentication.

```
@Override
protected void onCreate(Bundle savedInstanceState) {
    super.onCreate(savedInstanceState);

    //set up the datahelper
    dh = new DataHelper(this, null);
    tae = dh.GetAuthenticationObject();
    setContentView(R.layout.main);
}

@Override
protected void onResume() {
    super.onResume();
    selectOption(getIntent());
}

public void selectOption(Intent intent) {
    Uri uri = intent.getData();
    if (uri != null && uri.toString().startsWith(CALLBACKURL) && tae.hasBeenAuthenticatedTwitter()) {           
        completeAuth(intent);           
    } else {
        doOauth();
    }
}

private void doOauth() {
    try {
        consumer = new CommonsHttpOAuthConsumer(Enums.TWITTER_APPLICATION_KEY,
                Enums.TWITTER_APPLICATION_SECTRET);

        provider = new DefaultOAuthProvider(
                Enums.TWITTER_REQUEST_TOKEN_URL,
                Enums.TWITTER_ACCESS_TOKEN_URL,
                Enums.TWITTER_AUTHORIZE_URL);

        String authUrl = provider.retrieveRequestToken(
                consumer, CALLBACKURL);

        tae.TwitterToken =  consumer.getToken();
        tae.TwitterTokenSecret = consumer.getTokenSecret();
        dh.SaveAuthenticationObject(tae);

        this.startActivity(new Intent(Intent.ACTION_VIEW, Uri
                .parse(authUrl)));
    } catch (Exception e) {
        Toast.makeText(this, e.getMessage(), Toast.LENGTH_LONG).show();
    }
}

/**
 * After use authorizes this is the function where we get back callbac with
 * user specific token and secret token. You might want to store this token
 * for future use.
 */

public void completeAuth(Intent intent) {
    Uri uri = intent.getData();
    if (uri != null && uri.toString().startsWith(CALLBACKURL)) {

        tae = dh.GetAuthenticationObject();
        String verifier = uri
                .getQueryParameter(oauth.signpost.OAuth.OAUTH_VERIFIER);
        tae.TwitterVerifier = verifier;
        dh.SaveAuthenticationObject(tae);   
    }

    Intent settingsIntent = new Intent(this, com.undetowdevelopment.kontakt.Settings.class);
    settingsIntent.addFlags(Intent.FLAG_ACTIVITY_NEW_TASK | Intent.FLAG_ACTIVITY_CLEAR_TOP);
    settingsIntent.putExtra("REQUEST_CODE", Enums.REQUEST_CODE_TWITTER_LOGIN);
    settingsIntent.putExtra("RESULT_CODE", Activity.RESULT_OK);
    startActivity(settingsIntent);  
}
```

This class does exactly what I expect. It opens up the Twitter authentication page, returns to the activity and I save the `Token & Secret` to my Shared Preferences.

My `AndroidManifest.xml` looks like:

```
    <activity android:name=".TwitterSuccess" android:label="@string/app_name" android:launchMode="singleTop">
        <intent-filter>
            <action android:name="android.intent.action.VIEW"></action>
            <category android:name="android.intent.category.DEFAULT"></category>
            <category android:name="android.intent.category.BROWSABLE"></category>
            <data android:scheme="myapp" android:host="mainactivity"/>
        </intent-filter>
    </activity>
```

When my application launches however, I would like to check if the person is authenticated and not have to ask the user to authenticate again all the time.

From all my activities, I have a method that returns a Twitter object that I would like to use to set the status or to get the friends of the user.

I use the following method to do this:

```
public Twitter getTwitterObject()
{

    AuthenticationEntity ae = GetAuthenticationObject();

    CommonsHttpOAuthConsumer consumer = new CommonsHttpOAuthConsumer(Enums.TWITTER_APPLICATION_KEY, Enums.TWITTER_APPLICATION_SECTRET); 
    //Set the requestToken and the tokenSecret that you got earlier by calling retrieveRequestToken.
    consumer.setTokenWithSecret(ae.TwitterToken, ae.TwitterTokenSecret);

    //The provider object is lost, too, so instantiate it again.
    DefaultOAuthProvider provider = new DefaultOAuthProvider(
            Enums.TWITTER_REQUEST_TOKEN_URL,
            Enums.TWITTER_ACCESS_TOKEN_URL,
            Enums.TWITTER_AUTHORIZE_URL);

    //Now that's really important. Because you don't perform the retrieveRequestToken method at this moment, the OAuth method is not detected automatically (there is no communication with Twitter). So, the default is 1.0 which is wrong because the initial request was performed with 1.0a.
    provider.setOAuth10a(true);


    try {
        provider.retrieveAccessToken(consumer, ae.TwitterVerifier);
    } catch (Exception e) {
        Toast.makeText(mContext, e.getMessage(), Toast.LENGTH_LONG).show();
        e.printStackTrace();
    }

    Twitter twitter = new TwitterFactory().getInstance();
    twitter.setOAuthConsumer(Enums.TWITTER_APPLICATION_KEY, Enums.TWITTER_APPLICATION_SECTRET);
    twitter.setOAuthAccessToken(new AccessToken(consumer.getToken(), consumer.getTokenSecret()));
    return twitter;

}
```

Now this works fine if the user has just logged in, but if I launch the application again (which should not matter because I use only data from my static variables and Shared Preferences), I cannot authenticate and I get the following exception:

```
01-24 11:41:54.075: WARN/System.err(14612): oauth.signpost.exception.OAuthCommunicationException: Communication with the service provider failed: http://twitter.com/oauth/access_token
01-24 11:41:54.075: WARN/System.err(14612):     at oauth.signpost.AbstractOAuthProvider.retrieveToken(AbstractOAuthProvider.java:214)
01-24 11:41:54.075: WARN/System.err(14612):     at oauth.signpost.AbstractOAuthProvider.retrieveAccessToken(AbstractOAuthProvider.java:97)
01-24 11:41:54.075: WARN/System.err(14612):     at com.undetowdevelopment.kontakt.helpers.DataHelper.getTwitterObject(DataHelper.java:129)
01-24 11:41:54.075: WARN/System.err(14612):     at com.undetowdevelopment.kontakt.Settings.checkTwitterStatus(Settings.java:118)
01-24 11:41:54.075: WARN/System.err(14612):     at com.undetowdevelopment.kontakt.Settings.setUIComponents(Settings.java:60)
01-24 11:41:54.075: WARN/System.err(14612):     at com.undetowdevelopment.kontakt.Settings.onCreate(Settings.java:39)
01-24 11:41:54.075: WARN/System.err(14612):     at android.app.Instrumentation.callActivityOnCreate(Instrumentation.java:1069)
01-24 11:41:54.085: WARN/System.err(14612):     at android.app.ActivityThread.performLaunchActivity(ActivityThread.java:2751)
01-24 11:41:54.085: WARN/System.err(14612):     at android.app.ActivityThread.handleLaunchActivity(ActivityThread.java:2803)
01-24 11:41:54.085: WARN/System.err(14612):     at android.app.ActivityThread.access$2300(ActivityThread.java:135)
01-24 11:41:54.085: WARN/System.err(14612):     at android.app.ActivityThread$H.handleMessage(ActivityThread.java:2136)
01-24 11:41:54.085: WARN/System.err(14612):     at android.os.Handler.dispatchMessage(Handler.java:99)
01-24 11:41:54.085: WARN/System.err(14612):     at android.os.Looper.loop(Looper.java:144)
01-24 11:41:54.085: WARN/System.err(14612):     at android.app.ActivityThread.main(ActivityThread.java:4937)
01-24 11:41:54.085: WARN/System.err(14612):     at java.lang.reflect.Method.invokeNative(Native Method)
01-24 11:41:54.085: WARN/System.err(14612):     at java.lang.reflect.Method.invoke(Method.java:521)
01-24 11:41:54.085: WARN/System.err(14612):     at com.android.internal.os.ZygoteInit$MethodAndArgsCaller.run(ZygoteInit.java:868)
01-24 11:41:54.085: WARN/System.err(14612):     at com.android.internal.os.ZygoteInit.main(ZygoteInit.java:626)
01-24 11:41:54.085: WARN/System.err(14612):     at dalvik.system.NativeStart.main(Native Method)
01-24 11:41:54.085: WARN/System.err(14612): Caused by: java.io.FileNotFoundException: http://twitter.com/oauth/access_token
01-24 11:41:54.085: WARN/System.err(14612):     at org.apache.harmony.luni.internal.net.www.protocol.http.HttpURLConnectionImpl.getInputStream(HttpURLConnectionImpl.java:1162)
01-24 11:41:54.085: WARN/System.err(14612):     at oauth.signpost.basic.HttpURLConnectionResponseAdapter.getContent(HttpURLConnectionResponseAdapter.java:18)
01-24 11:41:54.085: WARN/System.err(14612):     at oauth.signpost.AbstractOAuthProvider.handleUnexpectedResponse(AbstractOAuthProvider.java:228)
01-24 11:41:54.085: WARN/System.err(14612):     at oauth.signpost.AbstractOAuthProvider.retrieveToken(AbstractOAuthProvider.java:189)
01-24 11:41:54.085: WARN/System.err(14612):     ... 18 more
01-24 11:41:54.885: WARN/System.err(14612): http://api.twitter.com/1/account/verify_credentials.json?include_entities=falseRelevant discussions can be on the Internet at:
01-24 11:41:54.885: WARN/System.err(14612):     http://www.google.co.jp/search?q=2486d84d or
01-24 11:41:54.885: WARN/System.err(14612):     http://www.google.co.jp/search?q=0d00203c
01-24 11:41:54.885: WARN/System.err(14612): TwitterException{exceptionCode=[2486d84d-0d00203c 175a68e8-9303e317], statusCode=-1, retryAfter=0, rateLimitStatus=null, version=2.1.12-SNAPSHOT(build: e7bec3eec13cedc774926ee24f4c5368d218c9d4)}
01-24 11:41:54.885: WARN/System.err(14612):     at twitter4j.internal.http.HttpClientImpl.request(HttpClientImpl.java:214)
01-24 11:41:54.885: WARN/System.err(14612):     at twitter4j.internal.http.HttpClientWrapper.request(HttpClientWrapper.java:75)
01-24 11:41:54.885: WARN/System.err(14612):     at twitter4j.internal.http.HttpClientWrapper.get(HttpClientWrapper.java:103)
01-24 11:41:54.885: WARN/System.err(14612):     at twitter4j.Twitter.verifyCredentials(Twitter.java:1397)
01-24 11:41:54.885: WARN/System.err(14612):     at twitter4j.Twitter.getScreenName(Twitter.java:191)
01-24 11:41:54.885: WARN/System.err(14612):     at com.undetowdevelopment.kontakt.Settings.checkTwitterStatus(Settings.java:120)
01-24 11:41:54.885: WARN/System.err(14612):     at com.undetowdevelopment.kontakt.Settings.setUIComponents(Settings.java:60)
01-24 11:41:54.885: WARN/System.err(14612):     at com.undetowdevelopment.kontakt.Settings.onCreate(Settings.java:39)
01-24 11:41:54.885: WARN/System.err(14612):     at android.app.Instrumentation.callActivityOnCreate(Instrumentation.java:1069)
01-24 11:41:54.885: WARN/System.err(14612):     at android.app.ActivityThread.performLaunchActivity(ActivityThread.java:2751)
01-24 11:41:54.885: WARN/System.err(14612):     at android.app.ActivityThread.handleLaunchActivity(ActivityThread.java:2803)
01-24 11:41:54.885: WARN/System.err(14612):     at android.app.ActivityThread.access$2300(ActivityThread.java:135)
01-24 11:41:54.885: WARN/System.err(14612):     at android.app.ActivityThread$H.handleMessage(ActivityThread.java:2136)
01-24 11:41:54.885: WARN/System.err(14612):     at android.os.Handler.dispatchMessage(Handler.java:99)
01-24 11:41:54.885: WARN/System.err(14612):     at android.os.Looper.loop(Looper.java:144)
01-24 11:41:54.885: WARN/System.err(14612):     at android.app.ActivityThread.main(ActivityThread.java:4937)
01-24 11:41:54.885: WARN/System.err(14612):     at java.lang.reflect.Method.invokeNative(Native Method)
01-24 11:41:54.885: WARN/System.err(14612):     at java.lang.reflect.Method.invoke(Method.java:521)
01-24 11:41:54.885: WARN/System.err(14612):     at com.android.internal.os.ZygoteInit$MethodAndArgsCaller.run(ZygoteInit.java:868)
01-24 11:41:54.885: WARN/System.err(14612):     at com.android.internal.os.ZygoteInit.main(ZygoteInit.java:626)
01-24 11:41:54.885: WARN/System.err(14612):     at dalvik.system.NativeStart.main(Native Method)
01-24 11:41:54.885: WARN/System.err(14612): Caused by: java.io.FileNotFoundException: http://api.twitter.com/1/account/verify_credentials.json?include_entities=false
01-24 11:41:54.885: WARN/System.err(14612):     at org.apache.harmony.luni.internal.net.www.protocol.http.HttpURLConnectionImpl.getInputStream(HttpURLConnectionImpl.java:1162)
01-24 11:41:54.885: WARN/System.err(14612):     at twitter4j.internal.http.HttpResponseImpl.<init>(HttpResponseImpl.java:47)
01-24 11:41:54.895: WARN/System.err(14612):     at twitter4j.internal.http.HttpClientImpl.request(HttpClientImpl.java:178)
01-24 11:41:54.895: WARN/System.err(14612):     ... 20 more
01-24 11:41:54.995: WARN/InputManagerService(99): Starting input on non-focused client com.android.internal.view.IInputMethodClient$Stub$Proxy@46113ee8 (uid=10060 pid=14093)
```

Like I mentioned, when I have just completed authentication, everything works fine, but If I launch my application again, I get this message.

I am using an `HTC Incredible`, running Android 2.2. The application is being developed for Android 1.6+.

Any comments or help will be greatly appreciated!

Best,

Ignus

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I am not really sure what you are doing, but you can have a look at Zwitscher https://github.com/pilhuhn/ZwitscherA and here especially at https://github.com/pilhuhn/ZwitscherA/blob/v065/src/de/bsd/zwitscher/LoginActivity.java method which is then calling into the TwitterHelper.

When the user first logs in and has never logged in, the activity checks this and shows a screen with the "getPinFromTwitter" button - this redirects the user to twitter where he can sign in and gets the pin.
The user starts the app again, enters the pin and clicks on "setPin".
In this version of Zwitscher, the account is stored in the database; in earlier versions (just check out the v065 tag for example : https://github.com/pilhuhn/ZwitscherA/tree/v065 ), this is done via shared preferences.
Source is currently a little bit in flux.

Comment: Hey Heiko, thanks for the reply. I have found my mistake, and was due to how I was handling the intent back to my Activity when the application redirects (using the callback).

Comment: can u share me demo code. i m also facing same issue

Comment: @Sandiskp I've updated the url to point to the v65 version mentioned. You should find all the code in above github repository.

Comment: i saw ur project but while getting pin error is Error 403 is coming ssl is required

Comment: even in my project i m getting same error please tell me how to solve

Comment: i saw ur project but while getting pin error is Error 403 is coming ssl is required and W/System.err(16099): java.lang.IllegalStateException: consumer key/secret pair already set. please help me how to solve these error . i m strugling from last 2 days on it. thanks